# Wrong command code jquery file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magento

When I click top navigation sub-menu of product page site has been redirect new popup blank window,after installed "askproductquestion" extension to my site. .

I found this problem and this issue have been from js folder which is askfordetails js file.

Here is the code;

```js
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
function popupWindow(url) {
window.open(url, 'popupWindow', 'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,copyhistory=no,width=600,height=650,screenX=150,screenY=150,top=150,left=150');
}
  $$(".popup").each(function(el) {
        el.observe('click', function(e) {
            Event.stop(e);
            popupWindow(this.readAttribute('href'));
        });
    });
});
```

But , I don't know how to fix this.

If you want to see issue,please check this product page navigation submenu on top bar and click any sub-category.
http://www.cherryconcept.com/red-agate-stone-mens-ring-ks-mr226

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that this code `$$(".popup").each(function(el) {` applies the popup function to every element clicked in the page that has the class `popup`. Your top submenu items are within divs that has the class `popup`:

```
<div id="popup5" class="popup" style="width: 180px; top: 39px; left: 102.734375px; overflow: hidden; display: none;"></div>
```

And therefore are being affected by that javascript.

To fix the problem, you should be able to rename either the popup class of your div (with the corresponding CSS styles) or use a different name for the class of the elements of the `askproductquestion` extension.

For instance you could change the name of the class name from `popup` to `popup-ask-question` and that should solve the problem. You will need to do it both in the JS code and in the template/s that have the following code:

Currently:

```
<a class="button popup" href="...">Ask Product Question</a>
```

Should be:

```
<a class="button popup-ask-question" href="...">Ask Product Question</a>
```

And for the JS replace `$$(".popup").each(function(el) {` by `$$(".popup-ask-question").each(function(el) {`